# Return an object from Protractor page object

Tags: javascript, angularjs, selenium, jasmine, protractor

I have a HTML table like this

```
<table>
  <tr ng-repeat='row in Entity'>
    <td>row.Name</td>
    <td>row.Surname</td>
    <td>row.Address</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

I want to create a function that returns an object with the values of the row number that I pass as an argument, like:

```
{
  name: 'name',
  surname: 'surname',
  address: 'address'
}
```

I could do it with a `map()`, but passing all the `tr` will return all the objects from the tables (is a very long table and it loads all the items from the `map` for about 10 seconds) and passing the exact `tr` will return **three** values for each `td`.

What should I do?

Comment: Is a repeater being used here? (assuming you've simplified the input HTML) Thanks.

Comment: Yes, I'm using a repeater to show the rows.

Comment: Could you please show the HTML source of the table without prettifying, as is? Thanks.

Comment: It's a way more difficult than that, I don't even use that data.

Comment: May be useful: [by.repeater](http://angular.github.io/protractor/#/api?view=ProtractorBy.prototype.repeater) has this `row` and `column` notions. Though `map()` sounds like a good way to solve it.

Comment: I edited it, maybe now it's more clear.

Answer (score 1):

There are many ways to do it. You can use [`map()`](http://angular.github.io/protractor/#/api?view=ElementArrayFinder.prototype.map) function to get the data you want, here's how -

```
function returnObject(eleIndex){
  return element.all(by.repeater('row in Entity')).map(function(elem, index){
        return {
            name: elem.$$('td').get(0).getText(),
            sur: elem.$$('td').get(1).getText(),
            addr: elem.$$('td').get(2).getText()
        }
    }).then(function(obj){
        return obj[eleIndex];
    });
};
```

Another easy way is to use the inbuilt [`filter()`](https://angular.github.io/protractor/#/api?view=ElementArrayFinder.prototype.filter) function which returns an element with the filter applied, in your case it would be the row number. Here's to use it -

```
function returnObject(eleIndex){
  var obj = {};
  return element.all(by.css('tbody > tr')).filter(function(elem, index){
      return index === eleIndex;
  }).then(function(elem){
      elem[0].$$('td').get(0).getText().then(function(name){
          obj.name = name;
      });
      elem[0].$$('td').get(1).getText().then(function(surname){
          obj.surname = surname;
      });
      elem[0].$$('td').get(2).getText().then(function(address){
          obj.address = address;
      });
    return obj;
    });
};
```

Another way is to use [`get()`](https://angular.github.io/protractor/#/api?view=ElementArrayFinder.prototype.get) function. Here's how -

```
function returnObject(eleIndex){
    var elem = element.all(by.css('tbody > tr')).get(eleIndex);
    var obj = {};
    return browser.wait(EC.visibilityOf(elem), 5000).then(function(){
        elem.$$('td').get(0).getText().then(function(name){
            obj.name = name;
        });
        elem.$$('td').get(1).getText().then(function(surname){
            obj.surname = surname;
        });
        elem.$$('td').get(2).getText().then(function(address){
            obj.address = address;
        });
        return obj;
    });
};
```

Usage of the above methods in your test spec would be same for both as they are returning a promise back to the calling function -

```
returnObject(0).then(function(obj){  //Return the object for first <tr> as both get() and filter() are 0 index based functions
    console.log(obj);
});
```

Hope it helps.

Comment: Wow, that's really ugly (don't say that is bad eh?), my real web use about 12 columns and that would be a huge function.

Comment: @J.J.Bocanegra If there are 12 columns then y dont u use a loop to get all the column data. I thought that there were only 3 of them and so i dint use a loop. I dont think there's another way to get the data returned from the promises and store it in the form of an object. But if your column elements have any special attribute that you can show, probably we can reduce the whole function. Thanks